# CL.exe exit codes

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Anyone know where I can get a list of CL.exe exit codes and what they mean?  Google is not my friend on this and the particular code I'm getting (4) also doesn't seem to get any hits.

Although the meaning to code 4 would be nice, I'd prefer a site that actually lists them all.

Comment: I'm sorry, but that's a really, really dumb question.  I want to know so that I can try to fix the problem.

Comment: dang, I got cl.exe exited with code -1073741515 :(  wish there was a list...nothing else in my logs about how it failed :(

Comment: i also have the same -1073741515 code :( no idea what's wrong

Comment: -107374151 == 0xC0000135 == STATUS_DLL_NOT_FOUND, "The program can't start because a DLL is missing from your computer".  Usually caused by getting the PATH wrong, use the Visual Studio Command Prompt.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Undocumented.  But it isn't unusual for a process to return the Windows error, COM failure HRESULT or exception code.  Which explains why it isn't documented.

Windows error code 4 is "Too many open files".  Got deeply nested .h files or recursive #includes without a guard?

Comment: Well, using boost so yeah, got deeply nested .h files.  It seems to be somewhat random though.  You can just go ahead and rebuild and it works sometimes.  Where'd you get the windows code?

Comment: The WinError.h SDK header file.

Comment: Yep.  Think you're on to what the code means.  It looks like the last file that was built (not the one showing on the "I blew up" line) has quite a few includes.  Why it sometimes errors and not probably has something to do with other processes.

Answer (score 2):

MSDN says only says "cl.exe returns zero for success (no errors) and non-zero otherwise".
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ebh0y918.aspx