# Targeting Windows XP using Build Tools 2015 without Visual Studio

Tags: c++, msbuild, target

I installed Visual C++ Build Tools 2015 on my machine running Windows 7.

In Windows SDK 8.1 and 10 there is no Windows XP targeting platform support.

It was introduced in Windows SDK 7.1A, but I can't find the download for it. It is also included in Visual Studio 2012 Update 4, but I would rather not install Visual Studio for it.

Is there any way to target Windows XP (**v110_xp**) using only Build Tools 2015?

Comment: You must use SDK 7.1.  Not hard to find, google "download windows 7.1 sdk" and take the first hit.

Comment: This post has a good writing about the relationship between Windows SDK and Visual Studio http://stackoverflow.com/a/34885950/5999.

Comment: @HansPassant, I tried 7.1 as you suggested, but 7.1 does not contain target v110_xp. I will try SDK 8 now.

Comment: Sure, you only get that with a VS install.  You have to configure the project yourself, VC++ directories settings and linker's System + Minimum Required Version setting   You seem determined to not build for XP, good idea.

Comment: @HansPassant, thanks for the answear. Do I understand you right that there is no way of building a vcxproj v110_xp without having VS installed? I thought that [Visual C++ Build Tools](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2015/11/02/announcing-visual-c-build-tools-2015-standalone-c-tools-for-build-environments/) were supposed to do that. Using it, I can build other projects targeting v140 easily, I just had to set global Variables pointing to Include and LIB path of the SDK. So no way without VS?

Comment: You can get it built, you just don't get the time-savers you get when you pay for the software.  Free software is only ever free when your time is free.

Comment: @HansPassant, I completely agree (except that it does not build)- and we live it that way: Develoment is done using licensed VS, but my target is to establish a jenkins buildserver, and on a buildserver there should be no IDE, I prefer a clean environment. In the past I have done that for C# and it was easy and clean and no problem, so I was surprised that it does not work for c++. It seems there is no way, It does not build. So i'll have to use VS. Case closed.

Answer (score 0):

I think SDK 7.1 + Visual Studio 2010 were the last version to support XP without having to install an additional taget [Windows SDK 7.1](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2010/06/15/windows-sdk-7-1/). But it is tricky to install old versions of that SDK if you have installed more recent version of VS. Also VS2010 doesn't have complete support for the C++11 since it predates that.

Since SDK 8 the compilers are not included, and should be installed from VS Express and/or Community. See this if you want to compile C++11 code tagetting XP [Configuring C++ 11 Programs for Windows XP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj851139.aspx). If I recall correctly the _xp taget was not included in the RTM version, and you should install the SP1.

Comment: The aim is _not_ to install VisualStudio and i have currently no version of VS installed. As you say compilers are not included in SDK - that is what the Visual C++ build Tools are for, they have all i need except from the correct target/SDK. I'll try with 7.1 as Hans Passant suggested.