# Visual Studio 2015 - Compile C++ with older SDK

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2015

I have VS 2015 installed on my PC and I want to build a project using the SDK shipped with VS 2010. I installed Microsoft SDK v7.1 but that didn't affect the environment for VS 2015 so that I can choose it as a toolset. Any tips?

This question ([Use Visual Studio 2012 and compile with older platform toolset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15453629/use-visual-studio-2012-and-compile-with-older-platform-toolset)) almost answers my question but I'm not if the SDK must be installed before VS 2015.

Comment: 1. Did you install Windows SDK 7.1 in default location? 2. Did you select to install compilers? It might detect you already have compilers installed and deselect them from installing.

Comment: I had to modify my registry to allow the compiler to be installed. Is there an install log for that?

Comment: Windows SDK installer asks you at the end whether you want to view the log. Try looking in your `%TEMP%` dir.

Comment: Oh .. shame on me. SDK installation had failed. A quick research on the cause led me to (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2934068). I had to uninstall the VC redistributable in order to install the SDK.

Comment: Now I remembered there is similar thread about it http://stackoverflow.com/q/34885286/70930